# Unable to access Active directory from my asp.net application hosted in production server

Tags: asp.net, ldap

I have written an asp.net application and validated the logged in user with Active Directory.
It works perfectly in my local machine IDE. But when hosted in my production server, it couldnt communicate with the AD Server.
I have windows authentication enabled in my IIS in server as well has put identity impersonate in my web.config.
The error is get is

```
Error Trace :System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007054B): The specified 
domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
```

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means exactly what it says - that it cannot find a DC to authenticate against for the specified domain.  Are you sure the production box can hit the domain via DNS?  You can use nslookup if the server is Windows.  This will confirm you can actually hit it.  You usually see a different error if it's a security/rights issue.

If it is a windows box try using nslookup domain_name and see if any IP addresses are returned.  If they aren't, then that's your issue.  You may need to manually configure the IP address if that's the case or resolve the potential routing issue if you can't hit it by IP.